# Cannot Subscript Value of Type JSON to an Index of Type JSON Error in Swift

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I am using Wunderground to gather history data, using SwiftyJSON. However, in the API, a section called "dailysummary" is curtained off in an array. Abbreviated, it looks something like this:

```
"history": {
    "dailysummary": [{
        "stuff": "here"
    ]}
```

I had tried to isolate the content inside the array with this:

```
var jsonData = json["history"]["dailysummary"]
var arrayData = json["history"]["dailysummary"][0]
jsonData = json["history"]["dailysummary"][arrayData]
```

This code returns an error saying it `cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'JSON'`. Is there any way to make this work, or a way to get the data from to array in this format?

Comment: You want something like: `var arrayData = json["history"]["dailysummary"][0]["stuff"]`. `arrayData` is a dictionary.

Comment: Wow. I had tried that earlier without success, and now that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
var arrayData = json["history"]["dailysummary"][0]["stuff"].
```

`arrayData` is a dictionary.